# Function isn't called on onclick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Width="245px" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" Width="250px" HorizontalAlign="Center" BorderStyle="None" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="" onclick="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("users") %>'></asp:Label></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

I don't want to use the auto generated select link or any button, I just want the label (or the link) itself to fire the selectedIndexChanged event.

The C# code is :-

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    show_chats();
}
```

But the event method is not being called. Please suggest what to do

Comment: Change that a tag to an asp:linkbutton. That isnt going to raise a serverside event.

Comment: try setting the `selectedindex="0"` and see if that helps, also place a breakpoint within your function to see if it is being hit at all

Comment: no its not being hit at all @pseudonym

Answer (score 1):

`<a onclick="...">` is strictly HTML markup, and the `onclick` is looking for a javascript function called `GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged`, not a server side method.  Change this to:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Comment: I'm using this:-

<a id="A1" href="#" runat="server" OnClick="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">

but still doesn't work

Comment: See edit -- forgot to change to `asp:linkbutton` @SohamBanerjee

Comment: Okay now it hits the function, but I click on the second row of the gridView and it throws null pointer exception, by debugging I find the selectedRow value is null

Answer (score -1):

If you dont want to use linkbutton, alternatively, you can do as follows-

```
<a href="" id="yourlinkId" runat="server"><asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("users") %>'></a>
```

And code behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        yourlinkId.ServerClick += new EventHandler(GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         show_chats();
    }
```

Comment: But then, I get this error: name does not exist in the current context and yourlinkId is showing error in the code behind

Comment: You cannot access the control directly as it is inside <ItemTemplate>

Comment: No I got error in this line:-

        yourlinkId.ServerClick += new EventHandler(GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged);